# Proving that $|P\{X=m\}-P\{Y=m\}| \leq P\{X\neq Y\}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables on the same probability space. Show that  for all $m$, $$|P\{X=m\}-P\{Y=m\}| \leq P\{X\neq Y\}$$

I'm actually not even sure how to start. I think it's going to rely on decomposing the right side into a sum of a form similar to

$$ \sum_i P\{x=i,Y\neq i\}$$
but am not really sure how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, $\left\{Y=X \right\}$ and $\left\{Y \neq X\right\}$  partition the space. So $\left\{X=m \right\} \subset \left\{ Y=m \right\} \cup \left\{Y\neq X\right\}$ and the symmetric statement (change the roles of $X$ and $Y$) give your inequality.